# UWP XAML: Custom font with FontIcon and HamburgerMenuItem isn't rendering glyph

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using the `HamburgerMenu` control from the UWP Community Toolkit in an app, because I want to support Windows 10 Mobile, so the new NavigationView control isn't an option for me.

I'm trying to use a custom font (FontAwesome) to draw the glyphs for my menu. This worked when I was using NavigationView, but now that I'm trying to use HamburgerMenu instead, I can't get the glyphs to render properly if I create menu items in my code behind.

Instead, the glyph reference displays as plain text. I tried inheriting `HamburgerMenuGlyphItem` and assigning the `Glyph` property, but that didn't work either.

Here's my page:

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
    xmlns:ct="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Tweeter.MainPage"
    x:Name="PageMain">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HamburgerMenuItem">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <FontIcon Grid.Column="0"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
                    Glyph="{Binding Icon}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Label}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ct:HamburgerMenu x:Name="navMain"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HamburgerMenuItem}"
                        ItemInvoked="navMain_ItemInvoked"
                        HamburgerVisibility="Visible"
                        UseNavigationViewWhenPossible="True">

            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="0">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
            </Frame>
        </ct:HamburgerMenu>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here's the relevant bits in my code behind:

```cs
private void LoadMenu()
{
    List <MenuItem> theMenu = new List<MenuItem>();
    MenuItem m = new MenuItem { Icon = "&#xf099;", Tag = "Feed", Label = "Twitter Feed", PageType=typeof(FeedPage) };

    theMenu.Add(m);
    navMain.ItemsSource = theMenu;
}

public class MenuItem : HamburgerMenuItem
{
    public Type PageType { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code-behind and XAML have slightly different syntax for Unicode characters. To get this to work, try this:

`MenuItem m = new MenuItem { Icon = new string('\uf099', 1)", Tag = "Feed", Label = "Twitter Feed", PageType=typeof(FeedPage) };`

Comment: Thank you!! I ended up going back to NavigationView after finding out that there's a preview version of the control available via nuget for targeting Windows 10 Mobile. This will still be helpful though. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of **FontIcon** Just use a **TextBlocK** font awesome icons in uwp works best with textblocks. I hope tis helps.

or better u can use them directly

```
<fa:FontAwesome Icon="Flag" FontSize="90" Foreground="Chartreuse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

more details : 
https://blog.codeinside.eu/2016/03/05/using-fontawesome-in-uwp-apps/

Comment: I would like to avoid using any third-party Nuget packages for this project. I'd rather figure out why my glyphs aren't rendering.

Comment: bcz they r nt supposed to render in FontIcon , fontawesome itself is a 3rd party service which u r trying to use in native controls, uwp is limited to segeo mdl2 asset icons ,if u want third party icons u will need third party libraries :)

Comment: btw libraries just make ur life easier, I thinku should use them more often specially in uwp

Comment: Using `FontIcon` with `FontFamily` works just fine. I was using that until I reworked my menu to use `HamburgerItem` instead of `NavigationView`.

If I don't create my menu items programmatically, it DOES work. The XAML works. For some reason it's not working when my menu items are added via code behind.

Comment: bcz when u bind it from backend then it generates at runtime and the runtime only expect mdl2 assets and not fontawesome icons, unless u tell it to expect that with nuget library. @ClairelyClaire